# IAB - purchase token when the subscription is cancelled and repurchased

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I recently integrated in app billing v3 to my app for monthly subscriptions. After I purchase a subscription, I use the purchase token and sku to sign up and login. For next launch, I use this purchase token again to login.

Even if I delete the app and reinstall, I again get this same purchase token which helps me login to app.

The problem seems to occur if I have cancelled the subscription and it has expired. In that case, I do not get a purchase token which is ok. I again purchase the same subscription using the same play store account. The purchase token received this time - will it be different or same? Shouldn't it be the same since I am purchasing the same SKU and using the same playstore account?

But I think a new purchaseToken was generated. I have cancelled the subscription to compare but it will take a day for it to be cancelled and deactivated. Will confirm as soon as I am able to test it.

Every unique purchaseToken is used to signup a user. So if the user cancelled, and repurchased the same subscription using the same play store account, another new account will be created for this user. A user with a particular play account will have two different signups for the same subscription SKU. Is it possible to renew old cancelled subscription instead of launching the purchase flow again?